# How should esc_url be combined with trailingslashit?

Tags: escaping

Generally, I escape URLs when outputting content with `esc_url` like so `esc_url( get_home_url() )`. If I'd like to adding a trailing slash e.g. `/`, I'm combining it with `esc_url` by prepending. An example, `trailingslashit( esc_url( get_home_url() ) )`. I'm assuming it's the correct way of using it rather than other permutations e.g. `esc_url( trailingslashit( get_home_url() ) )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It is recommended to escape as late as possible](https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/security/escaping/#toc_3), but the function simply adds a trailing slash (`/`) (after removing existing one, if any), and I noticed [core also used `trailingslashit( esc_url() )`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/6.2.2/wp-admin/network/site-info.php#L89C21-L89C45), so I guess that's how we would do it.

- But that is not a definitive answer to your question (which is interesting, BTW), because there's no official statement regarding which format should be used.

However, there's a similar function, namely [`user_trailingslashit()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/user_trailingslashit/), which *conditionally* adds the trailing slash and applies a filter hook that's also named [`user_trailingslashit`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/user_trailingslashit/), hence in that case, the format should always be `esc_url( user_trailingslashit() )`.

Comment: thanks that's useful to know.